# Will removing my account remove all the answers and comments?

Tags: support, deleted-users

Does deleting/removing my account remove all the answers and comments?

Answer (score 9):

No.

You have licenced the content as [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) (as stated in the footer), so it is up to Stack Exchange to decide what to do with the content.

We usually keep it.

Comment: see - http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8318/did-programmers-change-to-software-engineering

Comment: The user already has started on a vandalism rampage.

Comment: Is it worth flagging the vandalism?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - please do

Comment: @Pekka웃 - thanks. On it

Comment: @ChrisF should I roll back the vandalism, or just flag and leave it alone?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I think I've got it all. There were five or six vandalised and deleted answers. If you spot any more flag it.

Comment: @ChrisF - I've rolled back ~20 vandalised posts. Looking at the OPs activity page helps ;)

Comment: Oh. Missed those.

Comment: No worries, I think that between us, we got them all, @ChrisF. Checking them all, though.

Comment: @Oded: You only overlooked one; I have already rolled it back. Anyway, it's sad to see a rage quit of a user who provided so much high quality content...

Comment: @honk - yep, saw you did. Thanks, and yeah, hope this is just a misunderstanding (OP seems to think that the Programmers name change had anything to do with their rep there or on SO).